# QGIS3 python: right(QTextStream) - getting unexpected type ' str'

Tags: pyqgis, string

I have a field type double that I need to reduce from 9 digits to 8 ie 123456789 -> 23456789. If I do it as an integer I loose leading zeros ie 10002345 -> 2345. I am attempting to use refactor fields to make the field a string then use right(x,8). Refactor is correctly returning it as a string field, however I continue to get the 'TypeError: right(QTextStream): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'' error.

```
processing.run("qgis:refactorfields", {'INPUT':CMLot,'FIELDS_MAPPING':[{'expression': '"CADID"', 'length': 10, 'name': 'CADID', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}],'OUTPUT':'L:\CMLot_test.tab'})
layer = QgsVectorLayer('L:\CMLot_test.tab', "CMLot_test", "ogr")
if not layer.isValid():
    print ("Layer failed to load!")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
CM_test = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("CMLot_test")[0]
iface.setActiveLayer( CM_test )
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
features=layer.getFeatures()
layer.startEditing()
for f in features:
    m=(f.attributes()[0])
    b=right(m,8)
    f.setAttribute(f.fieldNameIndex('CADID'),b)
    layer.updateFeature(f)
```

I thought the right function required a string field so I am at a bit of a loss of how to return the 8 right hand digits from the 9 digit integer without loosing the leading 0s.

Am I refactoring to the wrong field type or is my method for reducing 9 to 8 completely off the mark?

Comment: Well I am up to attempting to use lpad, however still not getting the syntax for using field calculator expressions in pyQGIS. Latest code attempt is: e=QgsExpression('lpad("CADID" ,8,'0')') to no effect, now getting syntax errors.